# Why are ECC/Registered 8GB DDR3 DIMM's so much CHEAPER than regular ones?

Tags: memory

I saw [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820139280&Tpk=N82E16820139280) and it got me excited for the possibility of having 16GB ram in a mini-ITX system.

Then I realized it is server memory.

I'd have to opt for [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820211564&Tpk=N82E16820211564) instead. More than twice as expensive.

Why? I was under the impression that Registered memory is more expensive to produce. They are able to cram 18 memory chips onto that module where normal ones only have 8 chips. I suspect that under the Adata heatspreaders they only have 16 chips. Are there strange economic factors at play here?

Comment: You have to add more capacity to store the ECC checksums and registered chips are less produced/more expensive. The real reason, I guess, is that server people want reliablity more than anything and is less sensitive to price...

Comment: Oops I just realized I typed the title question wrong. Fixing now.

Comment: @billc.cn, One of the things I'm trying to figure out myself is that by far the ECC memory I've found is cheaper than the non-ECC.  (Let me have a "Huh?" from the congregation).  Perhaps it's just for the older computers I'm trying to upgrade, but it's not the first time I've discovered this.  Must be related to the [answer](http://superuser.com/a/344766/442573) below.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's due to basic economic principles in effect.

[**Supply and Demand**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_and_demand): The demand for such large RAM capacities on a single stick is mainly for servers at this time, and the amount manufactured (supply) will be higher.  So, both Supply and Demand are higher for 8 GiB ECC RAM sticks than they are for non-ECC, making them substantially lower in price.

[image: Supply and Demand]

There is probably a little bit of [**Economies of Scale**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economies_of_scale) going on as well, making the increased manufacturing of 8 GiB ECC sticks cheaper, even though they include more RAM chips, but S&D will be the main factor.

[image: Ecomomies of Scale]

Comment: Okay. Does this mean that basically it makes more sense for a manufacturer (for whatever reasons) to sell their unregistered desktop 8GB DIMMs at $200 each today, even if it only costs them $60 to produce them? It just seems to me that the demand would go up if they lowered the price....

Comment: @Steven: No.  You need to read up on S&D. Because Demand is low at this time they cannot manufacture higher Quantities to increase supply without making a loss.  Competition is another factor which determines Supply.  Prices are not set arbitrarily, but determined to maximise Profit taking competition into account.

Comment: Okay, so the defining aspect of the situation is the low demand for desktop ram. Yes I am satisfied with that.

Comment: @Steven: Not just Demand.  Supply as well.  Think about the reasons why DDR2 RAM is now more expensive than DDR3.